# Dynamic Pictures Adding in table View

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, xcode-6.2

I'm trying to do a bit tricky thing for me (new to the layout constraints thing).

The idea is that I have to dynamically add pictures to a table cell.The cell structure is:

1. an image view
2. text view
3. scroll view (horizontal scrolling) 
   which contain images inside the images part & number isn't always there neither it's constant (Some Cells contains images & texts and the others only text) that's why i need to add the constraints programatically.

I've searched a lot and applied a lot of things but now I'm getting exceptions and the application is crashing. Hope u can help me.
Here's my code:

```
        var imgsScrollView = UIScrollView()
        cell.employmentEventTextView.text = employmentEventsList[indexPath.row].body
        if (imgsCountintheCell == 1){
            eventsListView.rowHeight = 220
        }else{
            eventsListView.rowHeight = 500
        }
        for var i = 0 ; i < imgsCountintheCell ; i++ {

            if(i == 0){

                var int : String = String(i)
                //getting the image from URL Block
                var imgName = "image" + int
                let url = NSURL(string: employmentEventsList[indexPath.row].imgs[i])
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                let imgView = UIImageView(image: image!)
                imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
                imgView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

                var constX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imgView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                var constTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imgView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell.employmentEventTextView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 2)

                var textPlaceBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.employmentEventTextView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: imgView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 2)
                eventsListView.addSubview(imgView)
                imgView.addConstraint(constX)
                imgView.addConstraint(constTop)
                cell.employmentEventTextView.addConstraint(textPlaceBottom)

            }else{
                var int : String = String(i)
                //getting the image from URL Block
                var imgName = "image" + int
                let url = NSURL(string: employmentEventsList[indexPath.row].imgs[i])
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                let imgView = UIImageView(image: image!)
                imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
                imgView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                let constscrollViewToTheTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imgsScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.employmentEventTextView , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 5)

                imgsScrollView.addSubview(imgView)
                eventsListView.addSubview(imgsScrollView)
                imgsScrollView.addConstraint(constscrollViewToTheTop)

            }
```

and my exception code is:

```
Assertion failure in -[UIImageView nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.93/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3502
2015-05-27 01:49:58.097 طاقات علم[1713:38226] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unexpected use of internal layout attribute'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100cc1a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102819bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100cc18da +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   Foundation                          0x000000010115cb6f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
4   UIKit                               0x0000000101bdea77 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:] + 3483
5   Foundation                          0x00000001010e2b9e lower_1_attribute + 158
6   Foundation                          0x00000001010e26b4 -[NSLayoutConstraint _lowerIntoExpression:reportingConstantIsRounded:] + 102
7   Foundation                          0x00000001010d862e -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 96
8   UIKit                               0x0000000101bd0cf9 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 411
9   UIKit                               0x0000000101bd0f94 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraintWithoutUpdatingConstraintsArray:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 30
10  UIKit                               0x0000000101bd10bc -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 243
11  ÿ∑ÿßŸÇÿßÿ™ ÿπŸÑŸÖ                   0x0000000100910764 _TFCX15__ymcamGdqDduaj30EmploymentEventsViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 7892
12  ÿ∑ÿßŸÇÿßÿ™ ÿπŸÑŸÖ                   0x000000010091164f _TToFCX15__ymcamGdqDduaj30EmploymentEventsViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 79
13  UIKit                               0x000000010164be03 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 508
14  UIKit                               0x000000010162b901 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2846
15  UIKit                               0x000000010164178c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
16  UIKit                               0x00000001015ce1c3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001054d6c58 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
18  QuartzCore                          0x00000001054cb87e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
19  QuartzCore                          0x00000001054cb6ee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010543936e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010543a482 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010543aaed _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100bf6507 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100bf6460 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100bec293 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100bebbc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
27  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000104dcaa58 GSEventRunModal + 161
28  UIKit                               0x0000000101554580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
29  ÿ∑ÿßŸÇÿßÿ™ ÿπŸÑŸÖ                   0x000000010094c19e top_level_code + 78
30  ÿ∑ÿßŸÇÿßÿ™ ÿπŸÑŸÖ                   0x000000010094c27a main + 42
31  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000102ff5145 start + 1
32  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

thx in advance for any help

---

Update: 
I noticed a way to work around my problem and it seems to work, the idea is that I can use the concept of constraints of blank objects just gets disabled automatically (when an image view is empty the text view automatically moves upward) and I found it just okay for me.Easy & fast solution .
Now I have a question to ask: is there a way to make the same table have multiple values for the row hight ? ( for example the first and second row have row.hight = 60 because they have no picture and the third row has row.hight = 500 because it have pictures.)

**Is it possible to give each cell a separate hight value in the same table ?**

Comment: `toItem: nil` is that correct?

Comment: @gran_profaci 'toItem: nil' works when u just want to center things out with no relations to any of the surrounding items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I find it easier to create a nib file for cells, then 'collapse' constraints if certain views should be hidden. Eg create a nib with your UIImageView, UITextView and UIScrollView and all constraints. Add IBOutlets for the views and for the view's height/width constraints. Then if you need to hide a view, set its height/width constraint constant to 0.

Note as you should be recycling your cells you'll need to reset the constraint constants in -(void)prepareForReuse

You can set a different height for each cell by implementing the UITableView delegate method (in Swift the syntax will be different, but the name the same)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

For each row you can return a different height.

It can get a bit tricky with complex heights because sometimes you have to build you cell to calculate its height, then you have to build it again in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: thx for ur reply, I'm actually not familiar with the nib files nor with xib files.
I'll check this way out and try to work something out of it. and will get back to u with the results.

Comment: Sorry, nib is just an old school name for xib

Comment: It's okay, as I saw online the nib Name still has it's value in the swift language. Anyway i updated my question. check it out to see the new issues. thx

Comment: Updated my original answer